# Recover untracked files after doing git stash --include-untracked

Tags: git, intellij-idea

So basically I needed to checkout an old commit in order to see how the application was behaving back then. The thing is, when I did "git checkout", for some reason Git asked me to do something with the untracked files first and after googling, I saw "git stash --include-untracked".

The problem is, after doing this, I have now lost all my work. I tried to go back to my lastest branch/commit, but the whole configuration in Intellij Idea is messed up.

Is there anyway I can UNDO all of this and go back to where I was before I screwed up?

I have tried a lot of different answers, like git reflog, git reset, git stash apply, but nothing helps. I am desperate.

Comment: Could you please go to Commit tab and then check "Shelf" tab there? It seems that your changes might have been shelved.

Comment: I don't have a "Shelf" tab to be honest. Maybe it's an Ultimate feature?

Answer (score 1):

Run `git log --oneline --graph stash`, you should have a clear enough view of how the commits created by `git stash` are related one to another.

You will also see that your content is not lost (it is somehow stored in git).

---

When you run `git stash --include-untracked`, `git` creates a stash where the untracked content is accessible at `stash^2`.

To restore the `.idea/` directory, for example, just run :

```
git restore -s stash^2 -W -- .idea/
```

---

To completely undo your `git stash` action, the safest way is to come back to the commit you stashed from and run `git stash pop` :

```
git checkout <the/previous/branch>
# or use the following shortcut :
git checkout -

git stash pop
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is I don't remember exactly what commit I stashed from, since I needed to checkout a few of them :/ By the way, rather than restoring a specific folder, I would like the whole project to go back to whatever it was before I did that "stash untracked files" step, it that's even possible.

Comment: @Javdev22: this is stored in git too : look at the first parent of the `stash` commit : `stash~`. To find the branche(s) that point at that commit : `git branch --points-at stash~`.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I'm not sure how, but I managed to get it all back. I think what made the trick was the visual git tree in Intellij. I used the "revert back to 'whatever' commit" and it worked. I never managed to get the Tomcat config back though, that I had to redo manually.